# Animation stops after mousemove (canvas)

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I created a script that makes a canvas circle follow the mouse when is X is bigger.However as you can see it only works during the mouse move. when the mouse stops I couldn't find a way to make the circle move. Plus, did i use the correct logic for making this code?

Heres a snippet:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var PI = Math.PI;
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
 return window.requestAnimationFrame       || // La forme standardisÃ©e
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || // Pour Chrome et Safari
   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || // Pour Firefox
   window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || // Pour Opera
   window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || // Pour Internet Explorer
   function(callback){                   // Pour les Ã©lÃ¨ves du dernier rang
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
   };
})();
function pos(canvas, evt) {
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return {
   x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
   y: evt.clientY - rect.top
 };
  }

function elm_fixe() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(050, 155, 255, 1)";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30, 1);

 for (var x = 0, y = 0, alpha = 1; alpha >= 0; alpha -= 0.1, x += 40) {          
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(050, 155, 255, " + alpha + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
 }
} 

function cercle(x, y) {
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, PI * 2, true);
 ctx.fill();
}


var x = 250,
 y = 250;


function bouger(e) {
 console.log(e.clientX)
 if ( pos(canvas, e).x > x) {
  x += 1;
 };
   
}

function draw(e) {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
 bouger(e);
 cercle(x, y);
 elm_fixe();
}




/*       window.requestAnimFrame(function() { 
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  window.requestAnimFrame(function() { draw(e) });           
 });
}
);
*/     

 window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  draw(e);
 });
```

```html
<canvas height="500" width="800" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code on SO itself. As for why it only moves on mousemove, you are only checking the positon when a mousemove event is fired, not anytime after, so you should only change your cursors position on mousemove and all the rest should update every frame.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't open, and even if it did, what part of your code will we be looking at?

Comment: @Che-Azeh I got it open and basically, he means _all_. Its not very long though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when experimenting with this it's important to focus on getting the task at hand done, so I removed your fixed drawn elements, as that's easy.

The main issue you are having is that you only update *onmousemove*, which could get in your way. The best thing to do is simply to store the mouse coordinates in a separate object, here I have done it as such:

```
var mouse   = {x: 0, y: 0};
```

After that, simply update the coordinates when the mousemove event fires. Now we remember the position, which means in the future you could actually animate this circle from point to point as it does not rely on the event to actually know the values.

A polyfill for `requestAnimationFrame` is actually no longer necessary, almost every browser supports it except some older ones.

```js
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx  = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function circle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

function draw(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circle();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}   

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX > mouse.x ? e.pageX : mouse.x;
  mouse.y = e.pageY > mouse.y ? e.pageY : mouse.y;
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

It might be better to rename some functions, just for future obviousness. I have also learned the hard way, a long time ago, that you should keep your function names in English, mostly because programming happens to be based on English. This way every user on this site can decipher what a function might do, and future developers will be able to debug your code without knowing french. For example, I would rename `circle` to something like `drawCircleAtMousePosition` - its a mouthful, but nobody can confuse what this function does.

Another advantage of using a stored variable is that you can do your `pos` (which is a really bad name for a function - maybe `localiseCoordinatesTo(canvas)`) right in the `onmousemove` event, so you never have to think about this at a later point.

### Update: Animating

Here is an implementation that uses a very simple linear interpolation to animate the circle from place to place:

```js
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx  = canvas.getContext('2d');
// We will need a from value, a to value, and store a time;
var mouse = {from: {x: 0, y: 0}, to: {x: 0, y: 0}, time: Date.now()};
// As well as a duration
var duration = 1000;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function position(){
  // This will calculate the position
  var time = Date.now(), progress;
  if(time > mouse.time + duration) 
    return mouse.to;
  else
    progress = (time - mouse.time) / duration;
  return {
    x: mouse.from.x + (mouse.to.x - mouse.from.x) * progress,
    y: mouse.from.y + (mouse.to.y - mouse.from.y) * progress
  }
}

function circle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  var pos = position();
  ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

function draw(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circle();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Update FROM to the current position
  mouse.from = position();
  // Reassign the to values
  mouse.to.x = e.pageX > mouse.to.x ? e.pageX : mouse.to.x;
  mouse.to.y = e.pageY > mouse.to.y ? e.pageY : mouse.to.y;
  // Update the animation start time.
  mouse.time = Date.now();
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help this is great ^^
I just have a question about this code here: is it possible to slow the move of the circle ?
My main goal is that it moves slowly ( like in agar.io if you know it :p ) but here it's so fast it seems to follow the cursor perfectly

Comment: Yes it is, but you will have to animate it. Let me implement it and post it as a little extra.

Comment: @Leo I'v updated it with a simple linear animation, which does what you want it to do. Keep It Simple, Stupid (KISS) is a good mantra to code by :)